# "Eduard will als klug angesehen worden sein" - "Wollen" als "behaupten dass" in komplexen Sätzen

Tags: sentence-structure

Im Deutschen gibt es den Ausdruck

> jemand will xyz gemacht haben
>
> jemand will xyz gewesen sein

mit der Bedeutung: "Er behauptet, es gemacht zu haben (oder: es gewesen zu sein), aber ich - als Sprecher - habe gewisse Zweifel, ob es stimmt, was er sagt."

Ich habe Schwierigkeiten bei der Anwendung dieser Wendung in komplizierteren Fällen. Insbesondere bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob der folgende Satz grammatisch korrekt gebildet ist:

> Eduard will schon immer als klug angesehen werden gewollt haben.

Die Bedeutung müsste sein: "Eduard behauptet, er habe schon immer angestrebt, als klug angesehen zu werden; aber ich zweifle, ob das stimmt." Ja, ich weiß, stilistisch ist der Satz nicht so toll...

(Zur Verwirrung trägt natürlich bei, dass hier das übertragene "er will" im Sinne von "er behauptet" zusammentrifft mit einem direkten "er will" im Sinne von "er wünscht".)

Hier ist eine Reihe von Sätzen aufsteigender Komplexität. Vielleicht hilft das beim Herausfinden, ob der Beispielsatz oben grammatisch korrekt ist.

> (1) Eduard will als klug angesehen werden.
>
> (2) Eduard will als klug angesehen worden sein.
>
> (3) Eduard will als klug angesehen werden wollen.
>
> (4) Eduard will als klug angesehen worden sein wollen.
>
> (5) Eduard will als klug angesehen werden gewollt haben.

Beispiel 1 hat eine interessante Doppelbedeutung. Der Satz kann bedeuten: "Eduard wünscht, dass man ihn für klug hält." Er kann abe auch bedeuten: "Eduard behauptet, dass man ihn für klug hält."

Beispiel 2 ist der Klassiker hier. Die Bedeutung ist: "Eduard behauptet, er sei in der Vergangenheit als klug angesehen worden."

Beispiel 3 sollte in etwa bedeuten: "Eduard behauptet, dass es sein gegenwärtiger Wunsch ist, als klug angesehen zu werden."

Bei Beispiel 4 bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob es überhaupt einen Sinn ergibt.  (Oder anders gesagt: Dass Beispiel 4 einen Sinn ergibt, will ich nicht behauptet haben.) Der Satz ergab sich einfach organisch aus der Reihe.

Beispiel 5 - der Satz, um den es hier eigentlich geht - müsste bedeuten: "Eduard behauptet, es sei in der Vergangenheit sein Wunsch gewesen, als klug angesehen zu werden."

---

PS: In die Zukunft gerichtete Varianten lasse ich hier einmal aus. Sie verwirren mich zu sehr.

> Eduard will als klug angesehen werden wollen werden.

Im Sinne von "Eduard behauptet, dass er in der Zukunft wünschen wird, dass man ihn für klug hält."

Comment: ... lol :-) ...

Comment: sample4 means what you expect 5 to be, perhaps at the end" gewollt haben" instead of "wollen" . But 5 itself doesn't make any sense (at least to my ears, which doesn't mean anything ;D )

Comment: "er will das gewollt haben", das = "als klug angesehen worden sein"  --> " er will als klug angesehen worden sein gewollt haben"

Comment: @Tommylee2k  - Ich glaube, beide Sätze sind möglich, und sie haben eine leicht unterschiedliche Bedeutung: *Er will als klug angesehen werden gewollt haben* = "Er behauptet, er habe (in der Vergangeheit) gewünscht, (in der damaligen Gegenwart) als klug angesehen zu werden." Dagegen *Er will als klug angesehen worden sein gewollt haben* = "Er behauptet, er habe (in der Verangenheit) gewünscht, (in einer noch weiter zurückliegenden Vergangenheit) als klug angesehen worden zu sein."

Comment: Der einfache Grund, dass dein Beispiel nicht richtig funktioniert ist: Es fehlt eine Negation. Duden schreibt nicht umsonst zu der Bedeutung "behaupten" "*meist verneint*"

Comment: @tofro   Du sprichst von... ?  Meinst du etwas wie *Er will nicht in Afrika gewesen sein* vs. *Er will in Afrika gewesen sein*?

Comment: Sowas meine ich. "Der Angeklagte will es nicht gewesen sein" funktioniert, wie du es möchtest. "Er will es gewesen sein" nicht.

Comment: @tofro   Im meiner soziolinguistischen Umgebung höre ich solche Sätze (ohne Negation) durchaus, sogar genau in dem Zusammenhang, den auch du als Beispiel bringst. Gespräch in der Vorhalle des Landgerichts: "Der Müller will es selbst gewesen sein, aber das nehm' ich ihm nicht ab. Ich bin sicher, der deckt irgend jemanden. Ich weiß bloß nicht wen."

Comment: (1) ist der einzige sinnvolle Satz den man verstehen kann. Die restlichen Sätze werden von 2 bis 5 immer konfuser. Sie hören sich lustig an, sind aber nicht mehr korrekt und sagen nichts verständliches aus.

Answer (score 7):

Mit den ganzen Verben am Ende des fraglichen Beispielsatzes wird die Aussage so kompliziert, dass man schon große Mühe hat, den Sinn zu verstehen. Daher wird im Deutschen ja oft auch eine kleine Umstellung vorgenommen, in der die Infinitive ganz an Ende versetzt werden.

Mal zur Verdeutlichung einen etwas einfacheren Satz: Wenn nach dem Willen des Herrschers niemand am Thron rütteln darf, kann man statt der Standard-Abfolge

> "der Thron, an dem niemand rütteln dürfen sollte"

auch schreiben

> "der Thron, an dem niemand sollte rütteln dürfen"

Nach dem gleichen Muster sollte man auch versuchen, Eduards Wunsch, als klug angesehen zu werden, umstellen - natürlich nur, sofern die Intention des Autors Verständnis auf Leser-/Hörerseite ist und nicht etwa ein "Hä???" die erwünschte Reaktion darstellt.

Comment: Ein guter Gedanke. Erinnert mich auch an dialektale Syntaxvereinfachungserscheinungen: *Das hättest du  nicht zu tun brauchen* --> *Dees hättsch it briechta doo* (Schwäbisch)

Answer (score 0):

Gütiger Gott! Da ist ja ein Versuchssatz verstiegener als der andere! Und ja, 'ungrammtisch' kann man steigern: einer ungrammatischer als der andere. Bleib doch einfach mal auf'm Teppich.

*Eduard will schon immer als klug angesehen werden gewollt haben.

-> Eduard wollte schon immer als klug angesehen werden.

Oder:

-> Eduard wollte schon immer als klug gelten.

So macht man das, wenn man Bodenhaftung hat. :-))

Cheers!